# Submit movie rating to imdb.com with curl

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I am trying to log in to imdb.com with curl and then submit a rating for a movie. I'm aware that this goes against their ToS but I'm not building an application or anything, just a small script for personal usage. I'm new to curl but I got the login part working by using information found on stackoverflow. After I login I set the curl URL to http://www.imdb.com/ratings/_ajax/title, because that is where a rating is submitted. However, when I execute the curl commands, no rating is submitted. Not sure how to troubleshoot this either, so hopefully somebody can point me in the right direction? Here's what I got so far:

```
// options
$username           = 'username';
$password           = 'password';
$url_login          = "https://secure.imdb.com/register-imdb/login"; 
$url_rating         = "http://www.imdb.com/ratings/_ajax/title";
$headers[]          = "Accept: */*";
$headers[]          = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
$headers[]          = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
$cookie_file_path   = dirname(__FILE__)."/cookies.txt";
$agent              = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36";


// get login page
$ch = curl_init(); 

// basic curl options for all requests
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
// log
$verbose = fopen("loginfetch.txt", 'a+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

// set first URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_login);

// execute session to get cookies and required form inputs
$return = curl_exec($ch); 

// close connection
curl_close($ch);

//echo $return;


// grab the hidden inputs from the form required to login
$fields = getFormFields($return);
$fields['login'] = $username;
$fields['password'] = $password;

// set postfields using what we extracted from the form
$postfields = http_build_query($fields); 

// post to login page
$ch = curl_init(); 

// set post options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_login);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
// log
$verbose = fopen("loginpost.txt", 'a+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

// perform login
$return = curl_exec($ch);  

// close connection
curl_close($ch);

//echo $return; 


//submit rating

$data['tconst'] = 'tt1709143';
$data['rating'] = '5';
$data['tracking_tag'] = 'title-maindetails';

$post = http_build_query($data); 

// post to submit page
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);                                                                                            
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_rating);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
// log
$verbose = fopen("ratingsubmit.txt", 'a+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

$return = curl_exec($ch);

// close connection
curl_close($ch);

//echo $return;
```

After enabling logging I get three logs. The third one logs the request to the IMDB rating page, which does not work as you can reed in the log below:

```
* About to connect() to www.imdb.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 72.21.203.211... * connected
* Connected to www.imdb.com (72.21.203.211) port 80 (#0)
> POST /ratings/_ajax/title HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36
Host: www.imdb.com
Cookie: cs=ECxJtiNrhA/m+SuIKh15AweBbbqgkVqM8BkNuqOS/TKzsu7Z84JeKeCRXRoA0U26oKcq7CWRbbqj9TkMh9HN2eCRWyxAGW26oKdbraCRbbqgsW26oJFt+uDBHYqg==; cache=BCYqeti-w3RKC8bV21R-BwArPk4ILOkGu0T6E1oB5KGihmddDp_kluyca1x7QLflsfnEZ9smi6EZc2uHo7eY5FZeXfG4EQ97tKKFR8VhyAW4d4Q; id=BCYiSjnWuGQc8HDlo5OAY8cDzxQyS5nHJqLgwq_9yI08DAjTU5l0CeOXL8dUvE28QUv1MNlBQ0MD5jEzs8OuhUVQKukg_AtlD58ORFostzT-mCzLCuv8a_mOFztCRGX7V3rpONDCl_xyKHAEj2JLSnWHI8VbKrpes93j5xsgNtdgeU0oYH3s93XMeRVWOM06V1Lg; session-id-time=1551966508; session-id=357-4286508-9576651; uu=BCYvAfd_f2bQLnYdtpdRlYkDth4AKSl6zlKVXzyzSLlagoM-bH3kvZe3FLFOj_KmoWbEkh-dRXiPZZtStWC72Dbsd6jCQiNnXDAyxc-_vmzg5yiJLuwbKVF6nICv9xuwCV_Gn-_Ek8gqTujYDQPdgIWR2Y3aXArES1RzXoqX1pA9jkZ1EkWFkVKNaukvSqxPQRJhE50xfMNMwaUJLJ8SLA1WRsIVLqp873yNvZf7ecyLd4hgmC7AxdbfzPtDCdwgaelx
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 56

< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Sat, 08 Mar 2014 13:48:30 GMT
< Server: Server
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Language: en-US
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
* Replaced cookie cache="BCYs4XPUvL_p2AL_pctQP7qEdwB9nBAXcIkiNxRZlqHtp9VjHkCy-GzvEIqsHCBHjjuGdWIyzZb1%0D%0Aip5WAl_SmYCtFg%0D%0A" for domain imdb.com, path /, expire 3541770158
< Set-Cookie: cache=BCYs4XPUvL_p2AL_pctQP7qEdwB9nBAXcIkiNxRZlqHtp9VjHkCy-GzvEIqsHCBHjjuGdWIyzZb1%0D%0Aip5WAl_SmYCtFg%0D%0A; Domain=.imdb.com; Expires=Thu, 26-Mar-2082 17:02:38 GMT; Path=/
< P3P: policyref="http://i.imdb.com/images/p3p.xml",CP="CAO DSP LAW CUR ADM IVAo IVDo CONo OTPo OUR DELi PUBi OTRi BUS PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA HEA PRE LOC GOV OTC "
< Cneonction: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.imdb.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what went wrong. There was a missing string that IMDb expects to be submitted along with the movie ID and rating. It's called "Auth" and it is a string that is present on the movie movie page. So I added a function that looks for the auth string and pass this when submitting a rating to the IMDb. No more error.

Here's the whole (working) thing in case anyone is interested:

```
// options
$username           = 'username';
$password           = 'password';
$url_login          = "https://secure.imdb.com/register-imdb/login"; 
$url_rating         = "http://www.imdb.com/ratings/_ajax/title";
$movie_id           = "tt1800241";
$url_movie          = "http://www.imdb.com/title/" . $movie_id;
$data['tconst']     = $movie_id;
$data['rating']     = '7';
$data['tracking_tag'] = 'title-maindetails';
$headers[]          = "Accept: */*";
$headers[]          = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
$headers[]          = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
$cookie_file_path   = dirname(__FILE__)."/cookies.txt";
$agent              = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36";


/**
    Step 1: get login page and cookies
**/

$ch = curl_init(); 

// basic curl options for all requests
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 
// log
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$verbose = fopen("loginfetch.txt", 'a+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

// set URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_login);

// execute session to get cookies and required form inputs
$return = curl_exec($ch); 

// close connection
curl_close($ch);

//echo $return;

/** 
    Step 2: post login credentials
**/

// grab the hidden inputs from the form required to login
$fields = getFormFields($return);
$fields['login'] = $username;
$fields['password'] = $password;

// set postfields using what we extracted from the form
$postfields = http_build_query($fields); 

// post to login page
$ch = curl_init(); 

// set post options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields); 
// log
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$verbose = fopen("loginpost.txt", 'a+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

// set URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_login);

// perform login
$return = curl_exec($ch);  

// close connection
curl_close($ch);

//echo $return; 

/**
    Step 3: get Auth string from movie page
**/

$ch = curl_init(); 

// basic curl options for all requests
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 
// log
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$verbose = fopen("authfetch.txt", 'a+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

// set URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_movie);

// execute session
$return_auth = curl_exec($ch); 

// close connection
curl_close($ch);

//echo $return_auth;

/**
    Step 4: submit rating
**/

$data['auth'] = getAuth($return_auth);

$post = http_build_query($data); 

// post to submit page
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);                                                                                            
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// log
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$verbose = fopen("ratingsubmit.txt", 'a+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

// set URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_rating);

// execute session
$return = curl_exec($ch);

// close connection
curl_close($ch);

//echo $return;



function getFormFields($data)
{
    if (preg_match('/(<form method="post.*?<\/form>)/is', $data, $matches)) {
        $inputs = getInputs($matches[1]);

        return $inputs;
    } else {
        return('Login form not found.');
    }
}

function getInputs($form)
{
    $inputs = array();

    $elements = preg_match_all('/(<input[^>]+>)/is', $form, $matches);

    if ($elements > 0) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++) {
            $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);

            if (preg_match('/name=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $name)) {
                $name  = $name[1];
                $value = '';

                if (preg_match('/value=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $value)) {
                    $value = $value[1];
                }

                $inputs[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $inputs;
}

// when submitting a rating to IMDb you also need to send an 'auth' string which we grab from the rating-list div on the movie details page
function getAuth($data)
{
    if (preg_match('/data-auth="(.*?)"/is', $data, $matches)) {
        $auth = $matches[1];

        return $auth;
    } else {
        return('Auth string not found.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cookie is empty when you submit the request. You need to close the curl handle every time you do `curl_exec`:

```
curl_close($ch);
```

This will store the cookies into the file.

So for your code you'll need to close it three times. Make sure you are initializing the curl again after closing, and also make sure you are pointing the cookie file accordingly every time.

Comment: I updated my script with closing and initializing the curl handle as you suggested (see updated post above), but it makes no difference because no rating is submitted after I succesfully logged in. Did I do it correctly?

Comment: The code looks ok. May be you are doing mistake somewhere else. Run the script again by enabling the option `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` for all. It will help you to see the requests and the response those are sending during each call.

Comment: Can we see the verbose output for the third one??

Comment: I added the log to the opening post.